# Monogame Object reference not set to an instance error

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, monogame, visual-c#-express-2010

Guys need help in this problem a while. I code in visual C# express 2010 and monogame 2.5 to make game in windows, load some image using Texture2D for the game and compile. But when I try to compile the project it gives me this error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    private static Game1 game;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        game = new Game1();
        game.Run();//This line gives the warning
    }
}
```

I try this code

```
Game1 game = new Game1();
game.Run();
```

but it didn't work, still it gives this error.

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Did I miss something or should I install something to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Maybe some underlying object is null?

Comment: You mean debug the framework it self? If that so, no. I haven't try it. and I am new in this monogame framework.

Comment: Generally "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is a runtime exception. You've said it's a compile-time error (and also a "warning", in one place). Please try to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've given, it sounds like the exception is being thrown from within MonoGame's `Run` method.

The first step in fixing this would be to get more information about the cause. The *best* way to do this would be to **build MonoGame from source**, along with your project, in the one solution. That way, when the exception is thrown, the debugger will break in the exact place within MonoGame the error occurs, and you can use the debugger to determine what the problem is.

The next-best thing - which you can do without needing the source - would be to view the details for the exception to **get a stack trace**. This will at least tell you what method is responsible for the exception. From there you can look it up in [the source code](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame) and see if that provides any additional information.

(For this *particular* exception, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", a stack trace is less helpful, as it gets thrown by the .NET framework (presumably due to a bug in MonoGame), rather than explicitly being thrown by MonoGame itself due to (for example) an error in API usage.)

---

**If I had to *guess* the cause** (and I do), I would guess that you're not setting up a `GraphicsDeviceManager` correctly in the constructor of your `Game1` class (note how your constructor runs before `Run`). And, instead of detecting that situation and throwing an informative exception, MonoGame ploughs on until it crashes.

But this assumes that everything else is working normally. It could also be a problem with, for example, MonoGame not being able to initialise the graphics device for whatever reason. Or numerous other things, really...

(Another option might be to try and build your game against XNA, and see if what result that gives.)

Comment: Great answer. Although, I would've suggested getting the stack trace first since it's far simpler than building MonoGame from source.

Comment: A valid point. Although, IMO, having the source is worthwhile because, although it is more effort up-front, the investment is likely to continue to pay-off into the future. (It has been a while since I've built MonoGame from source, though, and not for Windows, so I could be underestimating how difficult it is.)

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Monogame a default project always starts out like this:

```
 static void Main()
        {
            using (var myGame = new Game1())
                myGame.Run();
        }
```

This seems to work.